# Tensorflow multilabel classification with 76,000 possible labels

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, multilabel-classification

Based on text description (varing length of 1000 words), i have to tag into one or more possible label values (for single training sample).

Any suggesting algorithm to proceed further.

More concered in backpropogation in tensorflow (Loss, optimizer & accuracy).

Would be using glove vector (Make use of Pretrained from stanfold) as embedding layer.

Comment: how many instances of each class do you have ?

Comment: 1 to 10 label instances are possible for each sample data